# How to convert/wrap a sequence in scala to an Option[Seq] so that if the list is empty, the Option is None

Tags: scala, scala-option

I could do this with an if an statement, but there is probably a "scala" way to do this.

```
  def notScalaConv(in: Seq[String]): Option[Seq[String]] = {
    if (in.isEmpty)
      None
    else
      Option(in)
  }
```

Comment: `if` is an expression in Scala, which is uncommon in other language: using it this way looks "scalaish" to me

Comment: As you wrote it, your `if` wouldn't work, because the value of a one-branch `if` is always `Unit`. I've corrected it by adding `else`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can lift your `Seq` to an `Option`, and then filter it. Like this:

```
 def notScalaConv(in: Seq[String]): Option[Seq[String]] = {
     Option(in).filter(_.nonEmpty)
 }
```

Comment: Better to use `nonEmpty` than a double negative.

Comment: @MichaelZajac So that is what it's called. I couldn't find it with my quick search. Thanks :)